# Select the columns based on the condition

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `stu_enrollment` (
  `stu_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_day_1` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `class_day_1_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_time_1` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time_1` time NOT NULL,
  `class_day_2` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `class_day_2_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_time_2` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time_2` time NOT NULL,
  `class_day_3` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `class_day_3_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_time_3` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time_3` time NOT NULL,
  `semester` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `stu_enrollment` (`stu_id`, `class_id`, `class_day_1`, `class_day_1_type`, `start_time_1`, `end_time_1`, `class_day_2`, `class_day_2_type`, `start_time_2`, `end_time_2`, `class_day_3`, `class_day_3_type`, `start_time_3`, `end_time_3`, `semester`) VALUES
(115527, 123, 'Monday', 'Normal', '10:00:00', '12:00:00', 'Tuesday', 'Normal', '08:00:00', '10:00:00', 'Saturday', 'Blended Learning', '08:00:00', '14:00:00', '1899');

ALTER TABLE `stu_enrollment`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`stu_id`,`class_id`,`semester`);
COMMIT;
```

I have this table which contains 3 different class days. 
What select statement or any query that can allow me only to select 
stu_id, class_id, class_day_(n), class_day_(n)_type, start_time_(n), end_time_(n) where the class_day_(n) = 'Monday'.

For more clearly details, the columns I wanted to select is based on the day.

> Let say, if today is Monday, I only need to select the
>   class_day_(n)_type, start_time_(n), end_time_(n) based on
>   class_day_(n) which must contain "Monday".
>
> If class_day_1 is Monday, then I only select class_day_1_type,
>   start_time_1 & end_time_1;
>
> If class_day_2 is Monday, then I only select class_day_2_type,
>   start_time_2 & end_time_2;
>
> If both class_day_1 and class_day_2 are Monday, then I select
>   class_day_1_type, start_time_1 , end_time_1, class_day_2_type,
>   start_time_2 & end_time_2;

Thanks for your help, I think this is quite complicated, thank you for providing me a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO first you need slightly modify your scheme. Let's convert your table to next structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `stu_enrollment` (
  `stu_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `semester` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `day_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `class_day` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `class_day_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE `stu_enrollment`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`stu_id`,`class_id`,`semester`);
```

I think in this case you can easily write your query. Something like

```
SELECT stu_id,class_id,semester,day_id,class_day,class_day_type,start_time,end_time
FROM stu_enrollment
WHERE class_day='Monday'
ORDER by day_id
```

And a final advise. Read about database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you that you need to design your database better. Your database for now is so messy. Try to watch some videos about normalization. You can make it better. Good luck.